# How can i convert logical columns to numeric in R using dplyr?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, dplyr

i have a data frame that i import it from an excel (.xlsx) file and looks like this :

```
>data

# A tibble: 3,338 x 4
   Dates               A     B     C    
   <dttm>              <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
 1 2009-01-05 00:00:00 NA    NA    NA   
 2 2009-01-06 00:00:00 NA    NA    NA   
 3 2009-01-07 00:00:00 NA    NA    NA   
 4 2009-01-08 00:00:00 NA    NA    NA   
 5 2009-01-09 00:00:00 NA    NA    NA   
 6 2009-01-12 00:00:00 NA    NA    NA   
 7 2009-01-13 00:00:00 NA    NA    NA   
 8 2009-01-14 00:00:00 NA    NA    NA   
 9 2009-01-15 00:00:00 NA    NA    NA   
10 2009-01-16 00:00:00 NA    NA    NA   
# ... with 3,328 more rows
# i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

The problem is that these three columns A,B,C contain numeric values but after some 3 thousand rows.

but trying to convert them into numeric i did :

```
data%>%
  dplyr::mutate(date = as.Date(Dates))%>%
  dplyr::select(-Dates)%>%
  dplyr::relocate(date,.before="A")%>%
  dplyr::mutate_if(is.logical, as.numeric)%>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(!date,names_to = "var", values_to = "y")%>%
  dplyr::group_by(var)%>%
  dplyr::arrange(var)%>%
  tidyr::drop_na()
```

but the problem remains :

```
   date       var       y
   <date>     <chr> <dbl>
 1 2021-11-30 A         1
 2 2021-12-01 A         1
 3 2021-12-02 A         1
 4 2021-12-03 A         1
 5 2021-12-06 A         1
 6 2021-12-07 A         1
 7 2021-12-08 A         1
 8 2021-12-09 A         1
 9 2021-12-10 A         1
10 2021-12-13 A         1
# ... with 189 more rows
```

any help ?

Comment: Fix it on import, read_xlsx takes column  type spec as a parameter: `readxl::read_xlsx("file.xlsx", col_types = c("date", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric"))` . Or increase `guess_max` , by default it's 1000

Comment: @margusl in my real data set  i have the first column date and 1000 columns like A,B,C,so how i can modified it ?

Comment: If relying on a higher `guess_max` value makes the process unbearably slow, you could try to import the file twice and then bind cols, for example. First import the date column, then all the rest - If col_types is just "numeric", it's applied to all columns. Or perhaps it's easier to change sorting in Excel first so those integer values would be on top.

Comment: @margusl it worked with the argument adjustment `guess_max(min=5000)` so you can post it as an answer in the OP.Both your recommended solutions solved the problem.

Comment: ok. Though it would be interesting to know if the import really was considerably slower now when it had to check at least 3000 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summing up from comments:
it's usually easier to fix conversation errors closer to original source as possible.

`read_xlsx` tries to guess column types by checking first `guess_max` rows, `guess_max` being a `read_xlsx` parameter with a default value of `min(1000, n_max)`. If `read_xlsx` gets columns types wrong because those cols are filled with `NA` for the first 1000 rows, just increasing `guess_max` parameter might be a viable solution:

```r
readxl::read_xlsx("file.xlsx", guess_max = 5000)
```

Though for a simple 4-column dataset one shouldn't need more than defining correct column types manually:

```r
readxl::read_xlsx("file.xlsx", col_types = c("date", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric"))
```

If `NA` values are only at the beginning of some columns, changing sorting order in Excel itself and moving `NA`s from top before importing the file into R should also work.